# How to set padding to portion of text within TextView?

Tags: android, textview, padding

How to set padding to portion of text within TextView?
Specifically, i want to give left padding to part of text within textview. 
Also, the text within textview is the data received from server. Any Help Appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your layout file-> Go to your textView in layout-> android:paddingLeft="10".

Comment: I mean to say some part of text..not the entire text within textview!

Comment: Also, I can easily know the part of text where i have to put additional padding, as the server team provides me with a start delimiter for such text. But concerned about how to set padding to that part of text.

Comment: You have to take two textViews for this I think, and need to do String operations like subString(), trim() etc.

Comment: I have solved the problem.
I have used another TextView which has left padding. The delimiter helps me identify the text to set padding for and then set this text to other textview. For this i have used some of the methods of String Class, which includes, contains(), split().